# [Android][MenuItem]How to display title text when long press actionLayout?

Tags: android, kotlin, menuitem

I'm using `MenuItem` in my tool bar and some of the items require custom layouts, so I created actionLayout for them.
The UI looks fine, but when I long press the items that only have `icon` but no `actionLayout`, they'll show `title` as a toast below the icon, while those have `actionLayout` won't show anything.
**I want all items have same behavior that will show their title at the same place**(below the icon) during long pressing.

- MenuItem without custom layout:

```
     <item
        android:id="@+id/normal_item"
        android:title="@string/title"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
```

- MenuItem with custom layout:

```
     <item
        android:id="@+id/custom_item"
        android:title="@string/title"
        android:icon="@drawable/icon"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/layout"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom"
        />
```

btw, the item with actionLayout was unclickable so I set an onClickListener in `onCreateOptionsMenu` and it worked:

```kotlin
    @CallSuper
        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu, inflater: MenuInflater) {
            inflater.inflate(R.menu.myMenu, menu)
            menu.findItem(R.id.custom_item).actionView?.setOnClickListener {
                // do something
            }
        }
```

It's easy to also set a `LongClickListener` to the actionView, but how to make it show the title text like this? (image source: http://www.devexchanges.info/2017/01/android-tip-detecting-long-click-at.html):
[image]

Comment: I'm thinking that you should be able to simply use [`TooltipCompat.setTooltipText()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/appcompat/widget/TooltipCompat#settooltiptext) on the `actionView`, but I've not tested anything. I should mention that you won't need to set any other listener with that; it takes care of it all.

Comment: @MikeM. It worked!. No other listener is needed as you said. Thank you!  Can you post this as answer so that I can accept it?

Comment: Cool! No problem. I'm good, though. :-) Nothin' huge; just a quick suggestion. Please feel free to post an answer yourself, if you'd like, to finish up the question. Might eventually be useful to someone else, too. Thank you, though. I appreciate the offer. Glad you got it working. Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved this by simply using:

```
TooltipCompat.setTooltipText(myActionView, titleString).
```